# How to hide indirect dependency from compilation in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a library that I rely on that depends on another library with a very broad functionality. I'd like to be able to hide the indirect dependency from the compiler, but still have it packaged for the runtime. I'd say I want to change the indirect dependency's scope from 'compile" to "run" in my project. How can I do that in Maven?

To clarify:  the indirect dependency is a "utility" library that carries a lot of classes that I do not use and do not want to use (e.g., its own LogManager and Logger, or a class that's derived from Date). Since I am using Eclipse, I don't want to accidentally bring one of those classes in by hitting "Ctrl-Space" at a wrong moment.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why hide?

Answer (score 3):

Use [a dependency exclusion](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to hide the old dependency, like this: (here, we're hiding `sample.ProjectB`)

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

So this basically eliminates the use of the indirect dependency.   You can then add it back as a regular dependency of your project, with scope being whatever you want.

Comment: Mmmm.. you will have runtime problems (ClassNotFoundException) if you use this approach. This eliminates the library from the package d application as well.

Comment: OP stated that he didn't want the package available at compile time.  I would suppose that indicates OP won't have classnotfound exceptions then (i.e. if some library is used dynamically via reflection at runtime).  If this isn't the case, then OP shouldn't be attempting exclusion at compile time.

Comment: >>  "I'd like to be able to hide the indirect dependency from the compiler, but still have it packaged for the runtime". This sounds to me like the dependency is needed at runtime...